# Angular: How to force run unit tests when running Git push?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, git, karma-jasmine

I have seen Angular projects in which the unit tests are run every time a build is executed and also when running the git push command. If any tests fail during either command, the process does not execute until all your unit tests pass or unless you bypass. I would like to have this kind of set up for my project as best practice. Please help :)

Comment: I don't think it would be a good idea to run unit tests when running `git push` as both these are two different and independent processes and they should remain as is. A better approach would be to implement a **pre-commit hook** that prevents committing the code if there is any failing test(s).

Comment: You should take a look into husky that'll help you create a git hook directly from your package.json. That said, I don't think it'sa good idea to do that unless you have very few tests or if they are running blazingly fast. You'll get really bored otherwise. Nobody wants to wait 5mn before being able to push. You should rather rely on your CI for that. Pre commit or pre push hooks are good for quick stuffs like linting (and even that can take too much time) or running prettier for example.

Comment: use a package call husky. With that you don't have to worry about creating folders or files.

Answer (score 3):

To run builds, unit tests, etc before a commit or a push you can use a tool like [Husky](https://github.com/typicode/husky).

Answer (score 3):

Git provides a methodology to hook it's events using `.git/hooks`

you can add a folder to your project called `.git/hooks` and within that folder add a subfolder called `pre-commit` and within that you may place scripts that are to be ran.  This being whatever your test command is.

For example test.sh would contain:  `ng test`

More documentation about hooking git events can be found here: https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks

Let me know if you have any questions, I would be happy to revise my answer!

Comment: It's not `.githooks`, it's `.git/hooks`.

Comment: @phd you're right, my mistake, answer has been edited/updated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Add a package called *husky* as a devDependencies.

```
npm i husky --save-dev
```

Now catch the pre-commit webhook by using husky, to do that in your *package.json*, add this object:

```
"husky": {
   "hooks": {
       "pre-commit": "ng test"
   }
}
```

This will make sure that every time you make a commit, *ng test* runs before the actual commit happens.

Comment: How can we add multiple commands like ng lint, ng e2e, ng test etc in pre-commit?

Comment: You can componse multiple commands in a single line like 
"ng lint && ng e2e && ng test"